# mds error "No store registered for scope" for nonexistent volume

Tags: error, console, mds

My system log is flooded with error messages like the following:

```
mds: (Error) Server: No store registered for scope "/Volumes/Storage"
```

The volume in the error was in use on a previous machine before I migrated to my current machine. Several have suggested adding and removing that volume in the Spotlight Privacy settings, but that volume no longer exists. Is there an mds configuration file somewhere that I can edit so that mds no longer looks for that volume?

Comment: What version of OS X are you using? Is it a server version?

Comment: I'm running 10.7.2, not server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use Alfred, a utility similar to Quicksilver. I had previously configured it to search `/Volumes/Storage` for apps, but never told it to stop trying to index that volume once I migrated to the new machine.

I removed the `/Volumes/Storage` entry from Alfred's list of directories to index, and now the console messages have stopped.